# Windows firewall - "Use recommendes settings"

Tags: windows, firewall

I have this problem.
I should click on the key titled "Use recommendes settings" of the Windows firewall but remotely and using the command line.
I would need it because the ESET Endpoint Security keeps giving me a warning entitled "ESET Windows Security Center indicates that the feature is not installed or is not running properly".
But the Enpoint Security is installed, updated and working and the only solution to the problem is to click on the button entitled "Use recommendes settings" of the Windows firewall.
Also because i would have to do it on 50 PCs and pass them all to me would be a tragedy.
Thanks in advance for any info you can pass me.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably configure this using a group policy instead of doing it manually on each machine.

Unfortunately the “recommended settings” consist of several firewall rules that you will have to define manually in your group policy. While developing your policy it might be handy to have a test computer on which to compare.

You will want to [learn about configuring group policies.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/manage-group-policy)
You will also want to learn about [recommended firewall settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/best-practices-configuring).